# event delegation not working with @Html.RenderAction

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am rendering a page using @Html.RenderAction and I would like to update the page using `$.ajax()`, however when I try to do this, the click event is not recognized if I use the below code

```
$(document).on('click', '.saleType > a', function () {
    var saleType = $(this).text();
    alert(saleType)
    //ajax request made
});
```

but the click event is recognised if I use

```
$('.saleType > a').click(function () {
    var saleType = $(this).text();
    alert(saleType)
    //ajax request made
})
```

using the second block of code is not an answer as only the first click is recognised and all subsequent clicks are not recognised.

Why is my first block of code not working?

EDIT:
Thanks to @shyju I can see the code works in isolation, so my question is how do I debug this problem?

Comment: Works fine for me http://jsbin.com/cakizilozu/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: I was worried that this might happen :S how do I debug my problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks right to me. Your current version of `jQuery` may not handle properly the direct child selector `'.saleType > a'` in an event delegation context. I come up with 2 solutions:

- Update your `jQuery` version to the latest version (if it's not the case)
- Troubleshoot that way:

Example:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function () {
  var isSaleType = $(this).parent().is('.saleType');
  if(isSaleType) { /* your code */ }
});
```

If the first option doesn't work, you may have found out an issue. If so report it to the `jQuery` team: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues